# How to validate option from Facebook Combobox using Selenium - Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate the process of posting on Facebook Market and I can't select any of the options on the category field after you open the "Sell Something" window. I can use the .send_keys('category') to write the option, but I can't validate it. Because I don't validate it, actually click the option on the extended combobox that opens when you select that field, it will be replaced by the default value, nothing, and will show the placeholder text soon as I move on to the next field to fill.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\webdrivers\chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
# driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(6)
driver.get("http://www.facebook.com")
# Login to Facebook
driver.find_element_by_id("email").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("mail")
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").clear()
driver.find_element_by_id("pass").send_keys("pw")
driver.find_element_by_id("loginbutton").click();
sleep(10)
driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/marketplace/')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Vender algo"]').click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js_n"]/input').send_keys('Bicicletas')
```

Any help with this?

Much Thanks,

Gabriel Lima